# What to do for the echo to work. to print output on the browser and download csv?

Tags: php, csv

I have this code,

```
<?php
  require "vendor/autoload.php";
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  use \Objects\Csv as Csv;

  $csv = new Csv();

  $originalCsv = $csv->getCsv('OriginalInventory.csv');
  $updpateCsv  = $csv->getCsv('UpdatedInventory.csv');
  $finalCsv    = $csv->mergeCsv($originalCsv, $updpateCsv);

  echo "Duplicate Style #s: " . $csv->duplicate;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Items missing from Original CSV: " . $csv->missing;

  $csv->download();
```

and this method for download

```
  public function download()
  {
    # Download
    header("Content-Type:application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition:merge;filename=FullInventory-merged.csv");

    $output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
    fputcsv($output, $this->new[0]);
    unset($this->new[0]);

    foreach ($this->new as $key => $value) {
      fputcsv($output, $value);
    }

    fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");

  }
```

What to do for the echo to work. to print output on the browser and download csv?

Given my code, this will only download csv but not showing a print on browser.

Comment: Because you can't print in browser and give file to download at __the same time__. Period.

Comment: One request, one output; that's the way web requests work

Comment: I see...........